Background photo looks fine on Browser responsive but different on smartphone
Can you check this website of mine?
Website
If you switch to responsive on the browser, the background image is just like I want to be.
But on phone, the background image is wrong. It is somehow zoomed in (can't see myself).
It is a hero banner and I bind it in the CSS like this
.hero-bg {
    background: url('../img/hero-banner.jpg') 50% fixed no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
}

I also tried different settings like tried object-fit: contain and tried different scaling like 80% and different height also background-size: contain. Nothing works.
I also tried to upload a smaller photo for media query.. still the same problem.
Here is my settings for media query
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .hero-bg {
        background: url('../img/Klein.jpg') 20% fixed no-repeat;
        height: 100vh;
        background-size: cover;
    }

}

Here is the HTML snippet of the hero banner
<section id="home" class="hero-bg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <div data-aos="fade-in-up" class="col-md-5">
            <h1 class="text-warning mb-4">Son Hai Vu</h1>
            <p class="lead text-white">M.Sc. Computer Science</p>
            <p class="lead text-white">Stuttgart, Germany</p>
            <a
              href="#ueber-uns"
              role="button"
              class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-round btn-lg mt-2 smooth"
            >
              <small>
                <span class="icon-arrow-down-circle pr-2"></span>Go to Projects
              </small>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- col -->
        </div>
        <!-- row -->
      </div>
      <!-- container -->
    </section>

I have no other idea. Please help

IOS has a problem with background-attachment: fixed see https://caniuse.com/?search=attachment

Have you altered your website to take the suggestion from @Takuya2412 so we cannot now experience the original problem on an IOS device. What we experience is no parallax effect, just scrolling. This is why SO asks you to put a snippet within the question rather than point to an external site which gets 'mended' and so no longer demonstrates the original problem.

Mobile devices often have higher pixel density displays than desktop monitors.
Try adding this
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    .hero-bg {
        background-size: 200%; 
    }
}

Change fixed to scroll here background: url('../img/Klein.jpg') 20% scroll no-repeat;

Does this manage to keep the parallax effect (changing to scroll from fixed)?
